# Can you calculate an area of a curve using a string?

Tags: unit-of-measure, geometry

Take a look at [this curve](https://bytescout.com/files/images/examples/bytescoutpdf/curves.png).

Imagine that I have drawn this on a paper, and that I want to find the area of it. 
(The thickness of the line is assumed to be constant).

Assume that I use a string to trace the edge of the figure, then compare that to a ruler. Then I measure the height using the same method. I will get values for the width and height, so can I just say Area = Width $\times$ Height? I will be extending that curvy shape into a rectangle. So in this sense, could I not assume that the area is like that of a rectangle, namely  Area = Width $\times$ Height?

--

**EDIT**

If this is applicable, I'm really interested to know if this also works with a curvy shape that has non-constant thickness.

Comment: Yes, this works, at least in the constant-thickness case. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11735/how-to-prove-that-a-torus-has-the-same-volume-as-a-cylinder-with-the-height-equ/11738#11738

Comment: Okay, what if the thickness is not constant ?

Comment: If the thickness is not constant, you can try to estimate the average thickness and use that.  It will be close.

Comment: You mean take measurements at various heights and taking the average to be used as the overall height ?? How accurate will the answer be ?

Comment: @RossMillikan sorry forgot to tag your name to get a notification

Comment: Are you looking for an approximate value? What is meant by "thickness", I mean in mathematical terms?

Comment: @Maesumi  The height the of the curved line basically. The various thickness means that the height of the figure changes at various points.

Comment: It will be quite accurate if your average is.  If you take lots of measurements, or can take ones that represent the range well, it will be very good.

Comment: @RossMillikan Would your method work with a figure that looks like this ? http://imageshack.us/a/img593/2648/imagermqy.jpg

Comment: I would say horizontally across the middle is a little wider than average.  I would take 80% of that as the average width, take the length of the centerline, and multiply them.  You can check by cutting it out of paper and weighing against a square, or by plotting it on graph paper and counting squares.  I would bet on $\pm 20\%$ and think it is probably within $\pm 10\%$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you measure the length in the middle of the (thickened) line, then indeed the area is just this length times thickness - at least as long as the curve is smooth enough and does not bend back on itself.

Comment: What if the line has varied thickness across it ?? What will happen then ?

Comment: @NLed Then you would need to use integration. If $\ell$ is the length along the top and $h$ is the height then you'll need to calculate $\Delta A = h(\ell) \Delta\ell$.

Comment: @FlybyNight is that Height x Length x Integration of Length ? Integrate from what value to what value though ? Also, can I take the average of different heights and use that as an approximation to solve in A=WxH ?

Comment: @Nled What's your gut feeling?

Comment: @FlybyNight Not sure what you're trying to get it at.

Comment: @NLed I'm saying that I've given you a clue, and that for your own pleasure and satisfaction it's probably best that you spend a little while thinking about it yourself. If I just tell you the answer then you won't get any satisfaction and you'll probably forget within a few weeks. Have a think and let us know what you arrive at.

Comment: Would've preferred a more sound explanation from you @FlybyNight rather than clues and puzzles ...