# Finding the volume of a torus

Tags: calculus

> A torus (a doughnut-shaped object) is formed by revolving the circle 
>   $$x^2 + y^2 = a^2$$
>   about the vertical line $x = b$, where $0 < a < b$. Find its volume.

I have tried to create an integral that makes sense but I keep getting it wrong. We are learning shell method and disk method if that helps. I'm just stuck at where I should even start with this problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/11735/

Comment: [Theorem of Pappus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem) says the volume is $2\pi^2a^2b$